# Detecting three consecutive set bits in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I have an error with my code . I've got a given 32b input and an 6b output which should be incremented everytime when the input has 3b of 1 consecutively . For example if the input is `000...111` the output should be `000001`.

I tried this code :

```
input [31:0] in,
output reg [5:0] out,
input clock

assign n=0;
always @ (posedge clock) begin
**out <= in[n]?in[n+1]?in[n+2]? out+1 : out;**
n++;
end
```

with no success . Any ideas ?

Comment: This does not even appear to be syntactically correct verilog. Try using some parentheses. If you want help here you need to make some effort yourself.

Comment: out <= (in[n] && in[n+1] && in[n+2])? out+1 : out;

Comment: but using n like that probably will not synthesise

Comment: I'll give you a hint. Create a separate combinational logic block with a for loop that well tell you when to increment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved using the elegant solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911780/looping-through-bits-in-an-integer-ruby/10922528#10922528):

```
if  (in & (in >>1) & (in>>2)  != '0 )
 out <= out+1;
```

Basically, if the the bitwise AND of the number with itself shifted 1 bit to the right for three times is non-zero, you increment.