# Find available apartments given a date range, a duration, and a list of unavailable dates

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql, bit-manipulation

I have a puzzle which I'm hoping someone can help me solve

I have a table of apartment listings. Each listing has one or more 'unavailable' dates stored individually in another table, let's call it 'off_days'. e.g. a listing which is unavailable from the 1st until the 4th of Sept would have 4 entries in the 'off_days' table, one for each day.

I'm looking for the most efficient way to search (preferably on the database level) for listings with at least N consecutive available days between two calendar days ('available' is any day not in the 'off_days' table for that particular listing). e.g. "Show me all listings with at least 5 consecutive available days in September"

I've been thinking about how i would solve this problem in the real world (by looking at calendar marked with X's and scanning for free blocks) and started thinking about using binary to represent available/unavailable days. i.e. for a given week, 0111001 ( = 57) would tell me that there are at most three consecutive available days in that week.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911780/looping-through-bits-in-an-integer-ruby/10922528#10922528) seems like a good start once I have the binary number for a given date range, but now I'm stuck on how to calculate that number dynamically for a given date range, again, on the DB level.... any ideas? or thoughts about this approach or another approach?

Comment: It would help *a lot* if you provided a test case with read CREATE TABLE statements and test data, plus the expected result. And your version of Postgres (as *always*).

Comment: Find a simple test case to play with in the fiddle I added to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apartment is available for gaps in the off days.  That means that you want to know how big the gap is for each sequence, and the `lag()` function can give you this information:

```
select od.*,
       lag(unavailable) over (partition by apartmentid order by unavailable) as prev_una
from offdays od;
```

The actual number of days is the difference between the unavailable and the prev one minus 1.  Now, assume the two calendar days a `v_StartDate` and `v_EndDate`.  Now you can basically get what you want as:

```
select od.*,
       ((case when unavailable is NULL or unavailable > v_EndDate
              then v_EndDate + 1 else unavailable
         end) -
        (case when prev_una is null or prev_una < v_StartDate
              then v_StartDate - 1 else prev_una
         end) - 1
       ) as days_available
from (select od.*, lag(unavailable) over (partition by apartmentid order by unavailable) as prev_una
      from offdays od
     ) od
order by days_available desc;
```

The `case` logic is essentially putting in stop dates just before and just after the period.

This isn't quite complete because it has boundary issues:  problems when the apartment is not in `offdays` and problems when the unavailable periods are outside the range.  Let's fix this with a `union all` and some filtering:

```
select od.*,
       ((case when unavailable is NULL or unavailable > v_EndDate
              then v_EndDate + 1 else unavailable
         end) -
        (case when prev_una is null or prev_una < v_StartDate
              then v_StartDate - 1 else prev_una
         end) - 1
       ) as days_available
from (select od.apartmentId, unavailable,
             lag(unavailable) over (partition by apartmentid order by unavailable) as prev_una
      from offdays od
      where od.unavailable between v_StartDate and v_EndDate
      union all
      select apartmentid, NULL, NULL
      from apartments a
      where not exists (select 1
                        from offdays od
                        where od.apartmentid = a.apartmentid and
                              od.unavailable between v_StartDate and v_EndDate
                       )
     ) od
order by days_available desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going out on a limb by suggesting an approach even though I know nothing of Rails. If what I propose makes no sense, please tell me and I will remove my answer and slink away.

Suppose you interrogated the database merely to create an array that indicates whether the apartment is available on each date in a range of consecutive dates.  Suppose, for example, it looked like this:

```
A = true
U = nil
avail = [A,A,A,U,U,A,A,U,U,A,A,A,A,A,U,A]
```

For a given number of consecutive days, `n`, the date offsets that begin runs of at least `n` available days would be given by the following method.

**Code**

```
def runs(avail, n)
  avail.each_with_index.each_cons(n).map do |run|
    av, off = run.transpose
    (av == av.compact) ? off.first : nil
  end.compact
end
```

**Examples**

```
runs(avail,1) #=> [0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15]
runs(avail,2) #=> [0, 1, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12]
runs(avail,3) #=> [0, 9, 10, 11]
runs(avail,4) #=> [9, 10]
runs(avail,5) #=> [9]
runs(avail,6) #=> []
```

**Explanation**

Consider the `n=3` case above.

```
n = 3
enum0 = avail.each_with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: [true, true, true, nil, nil, true, true, nil, nil,
  #                  true, true, true, true, true, nil, true]:each_with_index>
enum0.to_a
  #=> [[true, 0], [true, 1], [true, 2], [nil, 3], [nil, 4], [true, 5],
  #    [true, 6], [nil, 7], [nil, 8], [true, 9], [true, 10], [true, 11],
  #    [true, 12], [true, 13], [nil, 14], [true, 15]]
enum1 = enum0.each_cons(n)
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: [true, true, true, nil,...
  #                           ..., true]:each_with_index>:each_cons(40)>
enum1.to_a
  #=> [[[true, 0], [true, 1], [true, 2]],
  #    [[true, 1], [true, 2], [nil, 3]],
  #    ...
  #    [[true, 13], [nil, 14], [true, 15]]]
enum2 = enum1.map
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: [true, true, true, nil,...
  #                           ...true]:each_with_index>:each_cons(3)>:map>
enum2.to_a
  #=> [[[true, 0], [true, 1], [true, 2]],
  #    [[true, 1], [true, 2], [nil, 3]],
  #    ...
  #    [[true, 13], [nil, 14], [true, 15]]]    
a = enum2.each do |run|
  av, off = run.transpose
  (av == av.compact) ? off.first : nil
end
  #=> [0, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, 9, 10, 11, nil, nil]
a.compact
  #=> [0, 9, 10, 11]
```

Consider the calculation of the array `a` above. The first element of `enum2` that `each` passes into the block, and assigns to the block variable `run` is:

```
run => [[true, 0], [true, 1], [true, 2]]
```

Then

```
av, off = run.transpose #=> [[true, true, true], [0, 1, 2]]
av                      #=> [true, true, true]
off                     #=> [0, 1, 2]
([true, true, true] == [true, true, true].compact) ? 0 : nil
  #=> ([true, true, true] == [true, true, true]) ? 0 : nil
  #=> 0
```

so the first value of `enum2` is mapped into `0`, meaning that there is a run of at least `3` days beginning on day offset `0`.

Next, `[[true, 1], [true, 2], [nil, 3]]` is passed into the block and assigned to the variable `run`.  Then:

```
av, off = run.transpose #=> [[true, true, nil], [1, 2, 3]]
av                      #=> [true, true, nil]
off                     #=> [1, 2, 3]
([true, true, nil] == [true, true, nil].compact) ? 1 : nil
  # ([true, true, nil] == [true, true]) ? 1 : nil
  #=> nil
```

so the second value of `enum2` is mapped into `nil`, meaning that there is not a run of at least `3` days beginning on day offset `1`.  And so on...

**Notes**

- The values in `avail` that indicate an apartment is available on a given date offest (the constant `A` above) can be any "truthy" value (i.e., anything other than `false` or `nil`); however, unavailable dates (represented by `U` above) must be represented by `nil`, as I use [Array#compact](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-compact) to remove them from arrays.
- It may be helpful to think of `enum1` and `enum2` as "compound" enumerators.
- `enum0.to_a`, `enum1.to_a` and `enum2.to_a` are provided to show what each enumerator would pass into its block, if it had one.  (`enum2` does have a block, of course).

Answer (score 0):

#### Candidate apartments

Using [**`generate_series()`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generate-series) and two nested [`EXISTS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) expressions, you can translate this English sentence into SQL pretty much directly:

```
Find apartments  
  where at least one day exists in a given time range (September)
    where no "off_day" exists in a 5-day range starting that day.
```

```
SELECT *
FROM   apt a
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   generate_series('2014-09-01'::date
                        , '2014-10-01'::date - 5
                        , interval '1 day') r(day)
   WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM   offday o
      WHERE  o.apt_id = a.apt_id
      AND    o.day BETWEEN r.day::date AND r.day::date + 4
      )
   )
ORDER BY a.apt_id;  -- optional
```

#### Free time slots

You can apply a similar query to get an actual **list of free slots** (the starting day):

```
SELECT *
FROM   apt a
-- FROM   (SELECT * FROM apt a WHERE apt_id = 1) a  -- for just agiven apt
CROSS  JOIN generate_series('2014-09-01'::date
                          , '2014-10-01'::date - 5
                          , interval '1 day') r(day)
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   offday o
   WHERE  o.apt_id = a.apt_id
   AND    o.day BETWEEN r.day::date AND r.day::date + 4
   )
ORDER BY a.apt_id, r.day;
```

For just the time slots in a **given apt**.:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (SELECT * FROM apt a WHERE apt_id = 1) a
...
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1b27d/7)

#### Database design

***If*** "off-days" typically consist of *multiple days in a row*, an alternative table layout based on [**date ranges**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rangetypes.html) instead of single days would be a (much) more efficient alternative.

[**Range operators**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-range.html) can make use of a GiST index on the range column. My first draft of the answer was built on ad-hoc ranges ([see answer history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25345930/revisions)), but while working with a "one row per day" design the updated solution is simpler and faster. The alternative layout with adapted queries:

[**SQL Fiddle** with range types.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a4904/1)

Related answer with a similar implementation with essential information:

- [Perform this hours of operation query in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108477/native-way-of-performing-this-hours-of-operation-query-in-postgresql/22111524#22111524)